# Why can't type parameter in Kotlin have any other bounds if it's bounded by another type parameter?

Tags: types, kotlin

Here is the minimal demo code that shows this problem:

```
interface A

fun <T1, T2> test() where T2 : T1, T2 : A {}
```

When I try to compile it, compiler will complain:

> Error:(81, 25) Kotlin: Type parameter cannot have any other bounds if it's bounded by another type parameter

I read [Kotlin Language Specification](http://jetbrains.github.io/kotlin-spec/#_bounds), but only find the following bound restriction:

> A type-parameter cannot specify itself as its own bound, and several type-parameters cannot specify each other as a bound in a cyclic manner.

It doesn't explain the restriction I meet.

I explore Kotlin's issue tracker, and I find an issue about this restriction: [Allow to inherit a type parameter from another type parameter and a class : KT-13768](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-13768). However, this issue has been rejected by the following reason (update on May 6th, 2017: this issue has been reopened by Stanislav Erokhin):

> I don't think we can compile the code correctly to JVM if we remove this restriction.
>
> By Andrey Breslav

So the question is: why can't we compile the code correctly to JVM if we remove this restriction?

The same demo works in Scala:

```
trait A

def test[T1, T2 <: T1 with A](): Unit = {}
```

It indicates that Scala can compile the code correctly to JVM. Why can't Kotlin? Is it a restriction to guarantee a decidable subtyping in Kotlin (I guess. Subtyping is undecidable for Scala (Scala has a Turing-complete type system). Kotlin may want decidable subtyping like C#.)?

Update after answered by @erokhins (https://stackoverflow.com/a/43807444/7964561):

There are some subtle issues when supporting something forbidden by Java but allowed by JVM, especially in Java interoperability. I find an interesting issue when digging into bytecode generated by scalac. I modify Scala code in demo as follow:

```
trait A

trait B

def test[T1 <: B, T2 <: T1 with A](t1: T1, t2: T2): Unit = {}

class AB extends A with B
```

Scalac will generate the following signature:

```
// signature <T1::LB;T2:TT1;:LA;>(TT1;TT2;)V
// descriptor: (LB;LB;)V
public <T1 extends B, T2 extends T1 & A> void test(T1, T2);
```

Invoke `test` with `test(new AB, new AB)` in Scala will succeed, since Scalas invoke signature `(LB;LB;)V`; but invoke with `test(new AB(), new AB());` in Java will fail, since Java invokes signature `(LB;Ljava/lang/Object;)V`, causing `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError` in runtime. It means scalac generates something cannot be invoked in Java after relaxing this restriction. Kotlin may meet the same issue after relaxing it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This restrictions was made because java(language) has it:

```
  interface A {}
  // Error:(7, 26) java: a type variable may not be followed by other bounds
  <T1, T2 extends T1 & A> void test() {}
```

And we suppose that this forbidden also in bytecode level.
I dig into it and seems like it is allowed, and scalac generate the following signature:

```
  // access flags 0x1
  // signature <T1:Ljava/lang/Object;T2:TT1;:LA;>()V
  // declaration: void test<T1, T2T1 extends A>()
  public test()V
```

So, we probably can support such cases it in the future versions of kotlin.

P.S. As far as I know Kotlin has decidable subtyping, and decidability isn't affected by this.

Answer (score 9):

If you add the following suppress annotation, it should work:

```
interface A

@Suppress("BOUNDS_NOT_ALLOWED_IF_BOUNDED_BY_TYPE_PARAMETER")
fun <T1, T2> test() where T2 : T1, T2 : A {}
```

Reference:
https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/bug-in-where/25011/2