# Type parameter cannot have any other bounds if it's bounded by another type parameter: what does this mean and how to resolve it?

Tags: kotlin, generics, type-bounds

I was implementing custom list class `MyList<T>` in kotlin. In that, I wanted to add `insertSorted` function, which inserts a new element into the list in sorted order. For that, `T` must implement comparator. So the prototype of that function will be `fun <C> insertSorted(ele: C) where C:T, C:Comparable<T>` But this is giving me *Type parameter cannot have any other bounds if it's bounded by another type parameter* error. I am not understanding what this error is. Also, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43790137/12357035) question did not help me much.

PS: The type I am passing to that function is declared as `class MyClass : Comparator<MyClass>`. So the bound `where C:T, C:Comparator<T>` is valid I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the meaning of the error, see this question:

[Why can't type parameter in Kotlin have any other bounds if it's bounded by another type parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43790137/why-cant-type-parameter-in-kotlin-have-any-other-bounds-if-its-bounded-by-anot)

But if your custom list contains elements of type `T` and you want to compare them, then `T` should implement `Comparable<T>`.

So this should be all you need:

```
class MyList<T: Comparable<T>> {
    fun insertSorted(ele: T) {
    }
}
```